# How do I set up mail.log in PHP?

Tags: centos, email, php, sendmail

I'm trying to set up mail.log in PHP. I updated php.ini's mail.log setting on the server:

```
; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
mail.log = "/var/log/myphpmaillog"
```

Created myphpmaillog:

`touch myphpmaillog`

And restarted the apache daemon:

`service httpd restart`

I sent a couple emails through the server and checked myphpmaillog, and it's still empty. It appears to have the right permissions. I'm on PHP 5.3 and CentOS 5.11.